# in-depth explanation of "se trata de"

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

I'm looking to understand the phrase 'se trata de'. I've looked extensively online at examples (linguee) as well as the previous post here ([What does "se trata de" mean?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13645/what-does-se-trata-de-mean)) but can't seem to understand the subtleties of it.  It seems to get translated as 'is' much of the time.  Any thought and/or examples would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you expand a bit by editing your question about which part of the answers to the question to which you link still left you puzzled?

Comment: I just put in the fourth vote to close, so I think closure is imminent.  This will probably feel pretty frustrating for you.  I think you might be fairly new to StackExchange and I'd like to make a suggestion.  What you would typically do in a situation like this is either to provide more details (as suggested by @mdewey) to try to make the question fly, or to place a bounty on the original question whose answers weren't satisfying for you.  But you don't have enough rep for that in this case.  So I will place the bounty for you.  However, I will say

Comment: ... that in the previous question, there is one answer that I think provides a sketch of the information you need: the one by Juan Delgado.  It's a good start.  I agree with you that that question needs a better fleshed out answer and that's another reason why I'm going to place a bounty.  I will request that you let me know in Chat or on Meta how you feel about the additional responses that will hopefully start coming in on the original question.  (Normally the person who placed the bounty would edit the question and/or write comments, to provide feedback, but you don't have the rep yet.)